# SQL Server 2005 Xquery namespaces

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, xquery

I'm trying to get some values out of an Xml Datatype.  The data looks like:

```
<Individual xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <FirstName xmlns="http://nswcc.org.au/BusinessEntities.Crm">Lirria</FirstName>
    <LastName xmlns="http://nswcc.org.au/BusinessEntities.Crm">Latimore</LastName>
</Indvidual>
```

Note the presence of the xmlns in the elements FirstName and LastName - this is added when we create the xml by serializing a c# business object.  Anyway it seems that the presence of this namespace in the elements is causing XQuery expressions to fail, such as:

```
SELECT MyTable.value('(//Individual/LastName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS FirstName
```

This returns null.  But when I strip out the namespace from the elements in the xml (e.g. using a Replace T-SQL statement), the above returns a value.  However there must be a better way - is there a way of making this query work i.e. without updating the xml first?

Thanks

John Davies

Answer (score 7):

You need to properly name the element you want to select. See [Adding Namespaces Using WITH XMLNAMESPACES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx). Here is an example using your XML:

```
declare @x xml;
set @x = N'<Individual 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <FirstName xmlns="http://nswcc.org.au/BusinessEntities.Crm">Lirria</FirstName>
        <LastName xmlns="http://nswcc.org.au/BusinessEntities.Crm">Latimore</LastName>
    </Individual>';

with xmlnamespaces (N'http://nswcc.org.au/BusinessEntities.Crm' as crm)
select @x.value(N'(//Individual/crm:LastName)[1]',N'nvarchar(100)') AS FirstName
```

Comment: Man, that is fantastic, really appreciate your help with this, works perfectly.  Thanks a million, J

Answer (score 0):

The * wildcard will also allow you to select the element without enforcing the explicit namespace. Remus' answer is the way to go, but this may assist others having namespace issues:

```
select @x.value(N'(//Individual/*:LastName)[1]',N'nvarchar(100)')
```